# How to Order Entities (ManyToOne association) when using DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect annotation

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

Using zf2 and **Doctrine**, I am generating a form for my Salesman class.
Salesman has a ManyToOne reference to Store (i.e., a store can have 1 or more salesmen)

Since I use **@Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")**, I have a drop-down list displayed in the form, which is exactly what I want.

What I would like to achieve, is sorting stores based on store's name property **in the frame of a @ManyToOne association**

Here is the HTML (generated) code that I have:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Store A</option>
    <option value="2">Store C</option> <- not ordered! probably because using row id for sorting.
    <option value="3">Store B</option>
<select>
```

And here is what I want:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Store A</option>
    <option value="3">Store B</option>
    <option value="2">Store C</option> <- good, now my store are alphabetically ordered :-)
<select>
```

**@Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")** accept **@ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})** optional annotation but this only works for @OneToMany or @ManyToMany :-(

Question:

How can I achieve ordering in my **EntitySelect** with my **@ManyToOne association?**

PHP source code excerpts:

```
<?php
namespace Customer\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Salesman extends AbstractEntity
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer\Entity\Store", fetch="EAGER")
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"readonly":"false"})
     * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Store:", "target_class":"Customer\Entity\Store"})
     */
    protected $store;

    ...
}

<?php
namespace Customer\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Store extends AbstractEntity
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Name: "})
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer\Entity\Salesman", mappedBy="store", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
     * @Annotation\Required(false)
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Collection")
     * @Annotation\Options({
     *     "label" : "Salesmen",
     *     "target_element" : {
     *         "composedObject" : "Customer\Entity\Salesman"
     *     }
     * })
     */
     protected $salesmen;
    ...
}
```

About the view (.phtml), nothing special to mention: just basic form.

```
...
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);    
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
...
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: See [the documentation!!!!!](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-3--extended-version) :)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Well... I create my form using $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
$this->form = $builder->createForm('Customer\Entity\Salesman'); so I'll try to find out the generated 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect' within the form and programatically change it. But it sems not the 'cleanest' way to proceed (when using annotation based form creation method)

Comment: I don't use annotations myself, so can't help out with that fact but afaik that's the only way to do it, currently. We have no `@Inject` in ZF2, if im not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for your comment: So I debug and found the EntitySelect element and could change the options so it works! Thanks for the hint (I credited you in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [url doc](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-3--extended-version) given by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958642/sam), I could figure out how to change the options of my EntitySelect **after** form generation and **before** form binding.

Here is how I did:

```
    $storeOptions = $this->form->get('store')->getOptions();

    /* mannually changing options.
       If someone knows how to achieve this using annotations, I am interested :-) */
    $storeOptions['is_method']   = true;
    $storeOptions['find_method'] = array(
        'name'   => 'findBy',
        'params' => array(
                'criteria' => array(), // no criteria since I want the whole list
                'orderBy'  => array('name' => 'ASC'),
        ),
    );

    $this->form->get('store')->setOptions($storeOptions);
```

And now my entity selector drop down list is alphabetically ordered. Thanks a lot Sam!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Team(s):", "find_method"={"name": "findBy", "params"={"criteria"={}, "orderBy"={"name":"ASC"}}}})*
```

Comment: Was the relation a @ManyToOne association ?

Answer (score -1):

add to the entity above the property

@ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})

[more info here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#ordering-to-many-collections)

**EDIT**:

ofcourse name and ASC need to be replaced by the values of your liking/needing

Comment: will try, but the doc state that "Additional to any @ OneToMany or @ ManyToMany annotation you can specify the @ OrderBy in the following way". Doesn't mention ManyToOne, which is my case... did you tried this successfully?